# Uploading multiple images for image tagging in a single request to alchemyapi

Tags: node.js, tagging, alchemyapi

I am trying to use Node.js with AlchemyAPI for image tagging. How can I upload or provide multiple URLs for multiple images in a single request so that the response contains the tags for all the images ?

If I am adding multiple URLs it gives 
     "statusInfo": "content-exceeds-size-limit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlchemyAPI image tagging handles images one at time. You'll have to submit them individually, not as a batch. You can use multi-processing to increase the speed at which your program runs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I eventually realized the same !